# Logits and labels have different first dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

This was the error I got: InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [30,5] and labels shape [50]

I'm using a batch size of of 50. The number of outputs for my classification problem is 5.

I have no idea where the 30 in the logits shape is coming from. This is my architecture:

```py
with tf.name_scope("pool3"):

pool3 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID")

pool3_flat = tf.reshape(pool3, shape=[-1, 24000]) # must be a multiple of the input

pool3_flat_drop = tf.layers.dropout(pool3_flat, conv2_dropout_rate, training=training)



with tf.name_scope("fc1"):

flattened = tf.layers.flatten(pool3_flat_drop)

fc1 = tf.layers.dense(flattened , n_fc1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="fc1")

fc1_drop = tf.layers.dropout(fc1, fc1_dropout_rate, training=training)



with tf.name_scope("output"):

# n_outputs = number of possible classes

logits = tf.layers.dense(fc1_drop, n_outputs, name="output")

Y_proba = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="Y_proba")



with tf.name_scope("train"):

xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y)
```

Also here is how I declared my placeholders

```py
with tf.name_scope('inputs'):

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_inputs], name='X')

X_reshaped = tf.reshape(X, shape=[-1, height, width, channels]) # make applicable to convolutional

y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name='y')

training = tf.placeholder_with_default(False, shape=[], name='training')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is caused by `pool3_flat = tf.reshape(pool3, shape=[-1, 24000])`

You are supposed to check whether the 24000 is right.

Comment: So I should flatten it with the number of outputs by the pooling layers replacing 24000?

Comment: If you want to keep the original arch. you post, you should make it flatten with the size [batch size, -1]. It is strange actually, you can simply use tf.layers.flatten, which will keep the batch size unchanged.